# sys.stdout.write to file append mode

Tags: python

I try to figure out something, but I cannot find it on the manual. 
I want to log a logfile which is the redirected stdout.
I initialize it like this:

```
self.stdout_path = os.getenv('LOGPATH','/var/log/logfile.log')
```

and the logger part is simple too:

```
sys.stdout.write(msg)
```

It works nice (the daemon logs all the data what I needed), but there is only one problem, when I restart the daemon it opens the logfile again for write and empties it. I was wondering if I could open the logfile in append mode, but I cannot find how to achive this. I am not really sure if it is possible (because stderr is normally a special block device as /dev/tty). It would be nice to keep the current way - redirecting output - but if it isn't avoidable I can rewrite it to os.write - but I don't really want it.

EDIT:

okay, it seems the problem is because of the daemon library.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mambocollector", line 167, in <module>
     mambo_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(mambo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/daemon/runner.py", line 80, in __init__
     self.daemon_context.stdout = open(app.stdout_path, 'w+')
  AttributeError: 'Mambo' object has no attribute 'stdout_path'
```

So it seems I need to override this
             self.daemon_context.stdout = open(app.stdout_path, 'w+')

to

```
         self.daemon_context.stdout = open(app.stdout_path, 'a+')
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
sys.stdout = open(os.getenv('LOGPATH','/var/log/logfile.log'), 'a')
```

Comment: Sadly no: the daemon needs stdout_path to be set, but it gave me an idea